# Laravel - Too many redirects occurred

Tags: laravel, redirect

I've successfully set up Laravel middleware to check if the user is logging in for the first time (via a simple check for a null value in a `$user->last_logged_in_date field`). What I want is for these new users to be redirected to the `/password/reset` view so that they can fill in their email address and get a link sent to them.

I'm receiving a message of

> Too many redirects occurred trying to open “‎localhost:8000”
>
> This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another
>   page which then is redirected to open the original page.

My controllers all have `$this->middleware(['auth', 'new_user']);` referenced, and my middleware looks like the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;


class CheckIfNewUser
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = $request->user();

        if (! is_null($user->last_logged_in_date )) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('password/reset');
    }
}
```

Any guidance?

Comment: If the password reset controller also has `$this->middleware(['auth', 'new_user']); ` it would cause an infinity redirect

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

The password reset controller only has  $this->middleware('guest');

Any other ideas where I may be going wrong?

Comment: What about the controller that shows the home page ? is there any middlewares?

Comment: In my Home controller, I have: 

$this->middleware(['auth', 'new_user']);

Comment: And in your logging controller ?

Comment: public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understood correctly the password reset controller uses the
 `guest` middleware which expects the user to not be signed in. 
You have created a `new_user` middleware which kicks in when a user is logged in but new.
Therefore a new user who is logged in is sent to the reset controller which requires a guest, which you clearly are not because you are signed in, so it sends you back to your home controller which checks and sees you are a new user and so it sends you to the password reset .... you get the picture :)

Comment: Doh! How did I not see that? Thank you so much for your help!